# when someone mention the channel its writing in json file like this <#544554646> i want to be just the id not <#>

Tags: node.js, discord.js

****when someone mention the channel****

for example: !setlog #log 
its writing in json file like this

```
{
    "595632418111881229": {
        "channel": "<#544554646>"
    }
}
```

i just want the id like this

```
{
    "595632418111881229": {
        "channel": "68746544644644654"
    }
}
```

this is my code

```
const logsfile = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./log.json", "utf8"));
client.on("message", message=>{
  if(message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
  if(!logsfile[message.guild.id]) logsfile[message.guild.id]={
    channel: `nologchannel`
  }
  if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "setlog")) {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_GUILD")) return message.reply("**Sorry you do not have permission `MANAGE_SERVER`**");
  let logChannel = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
  logsfile[message.guild.id].channel = logChannel
  if(!logChannel) return message.reply(`xxxx`)
  message.channel.send(`**Log Channel changed to **\`${logChannel}\``)
  fs.writeFile("./log.json", JSON.stringify(logsfile, null, 4), function(e){
    if(e) throw e;
  })
}
});
```

and sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it looks like you are getting the argument to always be the channel, no matter what they enter. It is best for you to check if their input is a channel first before proceeding and storing it.

The `message` object has a property called [`mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions). With this property, it gives you the [`MessageMentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) object, where you can get the channels mentioned in the `message.content`!
For example, `message.mentions.channels.first()` gets the first mention of a channel in the message. With this information, you can get the ID by getting the `id` value from the [`GuildChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel) object.

In terms of your code:

```
const logChannel = message.mentions.channels ? message.mentions.channels.first() : null; // using a ternary operator, make sure there is a channel first before getting the first value (it'll cause an error if there is no first value)
if (!logChannel) return message.channel.send('No channel found!');
logsfile[message.guild.id].channel = logChannel.id; // this will set the channel property in the logsfile to be the id of the first channel mentioned in the message
message.channel.send(`**Log Channel changed to **\`${logChannel.name}\``);
// ...
```

The ID of a channel is not <#1234> but rather '1234' (the channel's snowflake).